# Giving error 500 ServerManager when i host website in iis

Tags: c#, iis

```
ServerManager iisManager = new ServerManager();
var webSiteList = iisManager.Sites;
```

This code is working in Visual studio, but when I host in local IIS it giving 500 error:

> Error: {
>       "Message": "An error has occurred.",
>       "ExceptionMessage": "Filename: redirection.config\r\nError: Cannot read configuration file due to insufficient permissions\r\n\r\n",
>       "ExceptionType": "System.UnauthorizedAccessException",
>       "StackTrace": "   at Microsoft.Web.Administration.Interop.AppHostWritableAdminManager.GetAdminSection(String
>   bstrSectionName, String bstrSectionPath)\r\n   at
>   Microsoft.Web.Administration.Configuration.GetSectionInternal(ConfigurationSection
>   section, String sectionPath, String locationPath)\r\n   at
>   Microsoft.Web.Administration.ServerManager.get_SitesSection()\r\n   at
>   Microsoft.Web.Administration.ServerManager.get_Sites()\r\n   at
>   Krosswall.Setup.Business.SetupBo.Setup(String companyName)\r\n   at
>   Krosswall.Setup.Controllers.SetupController.KWSetup(String
>   companyName)\r\n   at lambda_method(Closure , Object , Object[] )\r\n 
>   at
>   System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ActionExecutor.<>c__DisplayClass10.b__9(Object
>   instance, Object[] methodParameters)\r\n   at
>   System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ActionExecutor.Execute(Object
>   instance, Object[] arguments)\r\n   at
>   System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ExecuteAsync(HttpControllerContext
>   controllerContext, IDictionary`2 arguments, CancellationToken
>   cancellationToken)\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location
>   where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)\r\n   at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)\r\n   at
>   System.Web.Http.Controllers.ApiControllerActionInvoker.d__0.MoveNext()\r\n---
>   End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown
>   ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)\r\n   at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)\r\n   at
>   System.Web.Http.Controllers.ActionFilterResult.d__2.MoveNext()\r\n---
>   End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown
>   ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)\r\n   at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)\r\n   at
>   System.Web.Http.Controllers.AuthenticationFilterResult.d__0.MoveNext()\r\n---
>   End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown
>   ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)\r\n   at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)\r\n   at
>   System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.d__1.MoveNext()"
>   }

wwwroot folder permission

https://i.stack.imgur.com/eAQuE.png

Os and IIS description

https://i.stack.imgur.com/3UUxI.png

Answer (score 0):

I had problems like this a while ago.You need to make sure IIS/IUSRS accounts have permission to read/edit the folder where the website is located.

This often happens when you copy the folder from your dev location to the default IIS folder (wwwRoot) on your server/machine, as the permissions are not inherited from the wwwRoot folder.

1) Find the folder on your harddrive (The one you pointed to in IIS)

2) Right-click the folder and click Properties

[image: Folder Properties window]
3) Click on the Security tab

4) Click the Edit button

5) Add the IIS_IUSRS user if it is not in the list, and make sure you add the correct permissions: read / read execute

6) OK / Save

[image: Folder User Permissions window]
NB: Your folder location and name may be different. It's just the folder you pointed to in IIS that contains your website.

Hope that helps!
:)

Comment: Sorry, I didnt explain that very well. Basically, IIS does not have permission to read your config file. You need to add the permissions to allow IIS to do this, so that it can read your config, and then manage the website. Any questions, give me a shout / leave a comment. Regards.

Comment: Hi, I'll add that to the answer above.

Comment: please check permission in image file

Comment: Also see here.. https://forums.iis.net/t/1154515.aspx?ServerManager+UnauthorizedAccessException and https://forums.asp.net/t/1929969.aspx?cannot+read+configuration+file+due+to+insufficient+permissions.

Comment: Is there any way to read all hosted site in IIS and add a new site in IIS?

Comment: Can you update your questions with more detail as to what OS you are using, IIS version, where you are looking at hosting the site, and maybe a screenshot of your IIS Site details. Thanks.

Comment: Problem here is that the IIS_USER needs to be a member of the administrators group to actually do anything on IIS server level. You can however delegate user rights to non admin users but only on site level.
Consult: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732657(v=ws.10).aspx